# como importar un modulo si existe uno con el mismo nombre en python

Tags: python

Tengo dos archivos main.py, parser.py y quiero desde main.py importar parser.py pero no importa el parser.py que cree, lo que importa es un modulo parser builtin. Como puedo lograr que importe el archivo que cree sin tener que cambiarle el nombre. Estoy trabajando con python 3.6

Comment: Has probado en poner la ruta .parse al importar "import .parse"?

Comment: No es una buena práctica llamar a un módulo propio como uno built-in (compilado junto al intérprete y que pasan a estar en primer lugar en `sys.path`, no todos los de la stdlib lo son). Hay formas de hacerlo, modificando `sys.path` o vía `imp` por ejemplo, pero no es lo más legible para terceros ni lo más seguro. Cambiar el nombre de tu módulo debería ser la primera opción, o en todo caso crear un paquete que contenga al módulo  e importar por ejemplo con `from mypackage import parser` (los espacios de nombres son un buen invento XD)....

Answer (score 2):

tienes 2 maneras, utilizar **`__import__()`** directamente o cambiar el nombre del archivo que estas utilizando a que termine o inicie con _ para que no tengas que alterar tanto tu código.

Ejemplo:

```
parse.py >> parser_.py  || parser1.py
```

y solo utilizas el prefijo "`as`" para enmascarar al `builtin`, pero te recomiendo que reemplaces las llamadas a la biblioteca ya que es mas sencillo y seguro